# Install browsers in alpine container

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, firefox, alpine-linux

How can I install google chrome and firefox in alpine container for running selenium testcases ?
I need to download it using Dockefile ? I tried it using below command but selenium testcases are not identifying it. Is there some chrome alpine image in docker hub ?

```
apk add chromium
```